# Laptop charger voltage decreases gradually when plugged in, laptop won't charge

Tags: charger, laptop

Recently, I tried to charge a laptop I had not used in a long time, but it didn't work.

I took out a multimeter and measured the voltage coming out of the laptop charger, a Delta Electronics charger that is meant to output 19V at 3.42A, and noticed that the voltage was gradually decreasing from the moment I plug in the charger to the mains power supply. For instance, when I plug in the charger, the voltage starts off at 19.2 volts, but it goes down to 18V within a few seconds, 10V within 1 minute, and gradually approaches 0V over the next few minutes. This decline occurs even when I switch off and on the mains outlet switch, and the only way to get the charger to produce 19V again is to unplug it and wait for a few minutes - and the cycle repeats.

Is there something wrong with my charger? Greatly appreciate any info that could shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: It's not a charger, it's just a power supply. It might turn itself off if it sees nothing is connected, so we can't know that is normal or not, or if the problem is the power supply or laptop.

Comment: Maybe try giving it a load that will stop it applying any automatic standby facility. Something like a couple of 12V car lamps in series.